# Count frequency, ignore zeros

Tags: excel, excel-formula, frequency

I'm trying to count the number of unique values in row F in Excel for Mac. F contains a range of ID numbers but sometimes the ID is 0, which I want to ignore.

I'm using this function:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(F:F,F:F)>0,1))
```

which I adapted from the Microsoft Help page,how do I get it to ignore the zero? I tried taking out and changing the 0 in the function but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not pretty:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(F:F,F:F)>0,1))-IF(COUNTIF(F:F,"=0")>0,1,0)
```

Subtracts 1 if there are any zero values in the list.

I was trying to do it using an AND condition within the sum, but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Pretty or not, its clever thinking!